# How consistent heuristics guarantees A* optimality without adding same node to the frontier twice or more

Tags: algorithms, graphs, artificial-intelligence, search-algorithms

Taken from [Artificial Intelligence A Modern Approach](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mperkows/CLASS_479/2017_ZZ_00/02__GOOD_Russel=Norvig=Artificial%20Intelligence%20A%20Modern%20Approach%20(3rd%20Edition).pdf) :

[image: GRAPH-SEARCH]

Notice how a node doesn't gets added to the frontier twice in Graph-Search, And then take a look at this :

[image]

Now obviously this is not true as in the following example :

[image]

Bucharest will be added to the frontier first with path sibiu->fagaras->bucharest, while the second path which is more optimal will be omitted.

Am i missing something or is just a false claim?

Answer (score 2):

A* isn't based on the `GRAPH-SEARCH` algorithm but on the `UNIFORM-COST-SEARCH` one:

```
function UNIFORM-COST-SEARCH(problem) returns a solution or failure
   node ← a node with STATE = problem.INITIAL-STATE, PATH-COST = 0
   frontier ← a priority queue ordered by PATH-COST,
              with node as the only element
   explored ← an empty set

   loop do
     if EMPTY?(frontier) then return failure

     node ← POP(frontier)  /* chooses the lowest-cost node in frontier */
     if problem.GOAL-TEST(node.STATE) then return SOLUTION(node)

     add node.STATE to explored
     for each action in problem.ACTIONS(node.STATE) do
         child ← CHILD-NODE(problem, node, action)
         if child.STATE is not in explored or frontier then
             frontier ← insert(child, frontier)
         else if child.STATE is in frontier with higher PATH-COST then
             replace that frontier node with child
```

Uniform cost search algorithm is identical to the general graph search algorithm (in your question) except:

- for the use of a priority queue and
- the addition of en extra check in case a shorter path to a frontier state is discovered.

A* is identical to UNIFORM-COST-SEARCH except that uses $g + h$ instead of $g$.

So assuming the following distances (straight-line distance to Bucharest) for the `h` heuristic function:

```
Sibiu          253     Fagaras 176
Rimnicu Vilcea 193     Pitesti 100
Bucharest        0
```

the second path will NOT be omitted. Stages in an A* search for Bucharest  are (numbers show $f = g + h$):

```
(a) Sibiu 0 + 253 = 253
(b) Fagaras = 99 + 176 = 275, Rimnicu Vilcea = 80 + 193 = 273
(c) Pitesti = 177 + 100 = 277
(d) Bucharest (via Fagaras) = 310 + 0 = 310
```

A* search keeps going, choosing Pitesti for expansion:

```
(e) Bucharest (via Pitesti) = 278 + 0 = 278
```